# Set the Magento API URL to public address, not custom admin URL

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have a magento installation where we have public-facing nodes and an internally-routable-only custom url admin node (so, public hits market.example.com and customer service uses admin.example.com/)

When we have plugin vendors calling the API on the public nodes (market.example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=true) they get back a service address node describing the custom admin url (admin.example.com)

Is there a way to have the api serve the store url and not the admin url?

Based on this thread ([Magento SOAP V1 - Change Soap Address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/magento-soap-v1-change-soap-address)) it seems like it should be reading the url from the config to build the internal state variables, but how can I control which configuration state is used (so the default storefront instead of admin)?

Update - 10/2/15: I filed a case with Magento support and they have let me know that there seems to be a defect in the core causing this. We expect to have a patch issued early next week. I'll create an answer with the details once we have it and confirmed it solves the issue.

Comment: Did you get a patch? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in version 1.14.3.7. For versions before that, you can use patch PATCH_SUPEE-7029, like Ryan said.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on this - Magento provided us a patch for our version (EE 1.14.0.1), PATCH_SUPEE-7029, which did allow us to resolve the issue for the v2_soap endpoint specifically. We had an extension which used the original soap endpoint and it was not modified. So, our v2 stuff got happy, and we just had to hack a workaround for the v1 integrations.